# What is the effect of low variance features on machine learning models

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

intuitively it seems that low variance features are not useful and are just noise to the model. is it important to remove the features though? i.e., does the model performance improve significantly by removing irrelevant features?

I'm particularly interested in the effect on binary classification models.

Comment: Although i like this question a lot, please provide more details as to the context where these low variance features arise. For many models, e.g. neural nets, you don't care about absolute variance because they're normalized bef feeding into the models.

Comment: ***Note: This work is not yet published. I will add the reference of the paper after getting it published.*** Low-variance components can not be discarded completely. I constructed one class classifier for some senor data and observed that low variance features significantly reduces the False Acceptance Rate. At the moment, I am sharing the evaluation results of 3 different classifiers. 10 Components 20 Components TAR FAR TAR FAR #Iso 91.13029042 37.27786719 | 91.86305902 11.09181693 #SVM 77.75078828 7.36662317 | 76.19425188 3.44654686 #MCD 82.47419821 21.34011055 | 73.9477512 4.6335501

Answer (score 5):

> Intuitively it seems that low variance features are not useful and are just noise to the model.

This is folklore that is false in an essential way.  There are two intuitive reasons to doubt it:

- The variance of a feature is not unitless, by re-expressing, say, a length in meters, millimeters, or feet, you change the variance.  Any well founded model should not care.
- The variance of a feature ignores the relationship between the feature and the response, which is the focus of supervised learning models.  While the predictor may have small variation, the relationship between the predictor and response may be very powerful within that range.

With these points in mind, it's very easy to construct examples where a small variance feature dominates a large variance feature

```
> set.seed(154)
> x_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = .01)   # Low varaince
> x_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd =  100)  # High varaince
> 
> y <- 100*x_1 + rnorm(100) 
> 
> lm(y ~ x_1 + x_2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x_1 + x_2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x_1          x_2  
 -0.2394094   95.5194309    0.0007392
```

Any sensible measurement of feature "relevance" must take into account the relationship between a predictor and the thing being predicted.  The internal structure of the predictors themselves can tell you only very little.

Comment: This makes sense with the regression model. I edited my question: I'm interested in the models for binary classification. In this context, it doesn't make sense why low variance features are useful.

Comment: I don't think that's true, you could construct the same example for logistic regression.  Are you asking about binary *predictors*?

Comment: what do you mean by binary predictors vs logistic regression?

Comment: A feature in your model that takes the values $0$ and $1$ only.  Commonly created when encoding a categorical feature.  My point with logistic regression is that it can be viewed as a classification model, and you could construct the same example I gave above in that context.